# How is a line passing through the origin a convex cone?

Tags: convex-optimization, convex-cone

Currently, I am studying Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook). From page 27:

> **2.2 Some Important Examples**
>
> ...
>
> Any line is affine. If it passes through zero, it is a subspace, hence also a convex cone.

---

I am familiar with why a line is an affine set and that if it passes through the origin it is (by definition) a subspace. However, why does this make it a convex cone?

By definition, a set $C$ is a convex cone if for any $x_1, x_2 \in C$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2 \ge 0$,

$$\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 \in C$$

This makes sense and is easy to visualize. However, my understanding would be that a line passing through the origin would not satisfy the constraints put on $\theta$ because it can also go past the origin to the negative side (if that makes sense).

Comment: Let $L$ be a line through the origin, and suppose that $x_1, x_2 \in L$. Do you agree that if $\theta_1, \theta_2 \geq 0$ then $\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 \in L$? (If not, can you find a counterexample?)

Comment: Yes, I agree that $\theta_1, \theta_2 \ge 0$ since $x_1$ and $x_2$ lie on the same line and therefore their linear combination also lies on line $L$. However, aren't the linear combinations with negative coefficients (i.e. $\theta_1, \theta_2 \le 0$) also on $L$? This goes against the definition of the convex cone doesn't it?

Comment: If you agree with that, then you agree that $L$ is a convex cone.

Comment: The fact that $\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 \in L$ even if either $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$ is negative, does not make it any less true that $\theta_1 x_1 + \theta_2 x_2 \in L$ if $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are both nonnegative.

Comment: Forgive me if my understanding seems rudimentary, but I'm assuming that because convex cones have more constraints their set is larger than the set of lines passing through the origin, and therefore a line passing through the origin is by default also included in the set of convex cones. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Seankala It doesn't go *against* the properties of a convex cone, it just means that your set is something *more* than a convex cone.

Comment: [Listed](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33414/339790)

Answer (score 1):

If $x_1, x_2$ are on the same line that passes through the origin, there exists $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$ and a vector $v$ such that $$x_i = k_iv.$$

Let $\theta_1, \theta_2 \ge 0$.

Then $$\sum_{i=1}^2\theta_ix_i=\left(\sum_{i=1}^2 \theta_i k_i \right)v$$

which remains on the line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. If my understanding is correct, you're basically saying that because they are on the same line, the vectors are parallel and therefore remain on the same line even after multiplying with vector $v$, right? But I can't help but wonder, wouldn't this also hold if we choose $\theta_1, \theta_2 \le 0$? Then that would go against the definition of a convex cone.

Comment: The cone definition say check nonnegative $\theta$, it doesn't say that if $\theta$ negative, what should happen.